# Crystal Report Date of Maximum Value

Tags: crystal-reports

I am having difficulty getting the corresponding date of a maximum value.

I am trying to create a report where a parameter can be given and the maximum value within the parameter is given and the date when the value is recorded. I currently have it set up so I have a date parameter and the maximum value, but I am not sure how to get the date of the maximum value.

I am using a selection formula for the date parameter and using a Summary for the maximum value.

Answer (score 0):

Create a formula that returns a string concatenation of the value & "||" & Date

Get the maximum of that formula.

Use the Split() function to break that maximum into the 2 components and get the 2nd component.